# Git on production

Tags: git, version-control, versioning, gitlab

I want to make git on the production server (production server doesn't exist yet!!!)

Like you see I use GitLab on one virtual machine. Other VM will be production server and when the app is ready for production, admin will pull the app from GitLab to production server.

Only admin can pull,edit git. Pulling on production server can only be done from GitLab(Admin or Dev can't push app to production).

My questions are:

1. Is this logic ok?
2. How to undo changes on the last stable app(commit) when new version has bugs, and when dev fix all bugs how to pull these changes(with reset to stable commit)?

[image: My server logic]

Answer (score 1):

Make use of git tag.

Tag the latest stable version in the development server and push it to the remote.
From the production server checkout a new branch from that tag.